# Why does my back button not work on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)];
```

That's the code I'm using. When I tap the back button, the `backButtonTapped` method never gets called (I put a breakpoint on it) and I can command-click the `backButtonTapped` text to jump to that method, so I know it's there.

However, if I set it to `leftBarButtonItem`, no button shows up, but tapping that area brings me back.

Comment: Does the method have a parameter or not? Is the selector valid?

Comment: Sorry, typo, no it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by is the selector valid?

Comment: If the selector wasn't valid, the app would crash.

Comment: Oh, all it is is a popViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Using `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` sets the back bar button item for the **next** view controller (e.g. SecondViewController) that gets pushed onto the navigation stack, not for the **current** view controller (e.g. FirstViewController).

If you want to set the back button for the view controller that is currently on the stack, set it like you were doing with `leftBarButtonItem` in the current view controller, or use `backBarButtonItem` in the view controller that pushes this new view onto the stack.

The reason why no button showed up when you used `leftBarButtonItem` is because you left the title blank instead of setting it to something like "Back"

Examples:

```
// Inside SecondViewController.m
//
// Customize left bar button item for SecondViewController
//
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.navigationController action:@selector(popToRootViewControllerAnimated:)];
```

Or

```
// Inside FirstViewController.m
//
// Customize the back bar button item for SecondViewController
//
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Notice how you don't have to set a target or action for the `backBarButtonItem` since it will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your viewDidLoad method:

```
if ( [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] > 1 )
{
    UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backBtn setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
    [backBtn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [backBtn setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]; // <-- replace with your own image
    [backBtn setImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarBtnItem;
}
```